# Фиксированное значение столбца (= null) в зависимости от значения другого столбца

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

В таблице `tablename` есть столбцы `type` и `arg`. Нужно ввести ограничение, по которому при `type = 1`, всегда `arg = null`.

Каким образом это можно организовать в PostgreSQL? Версия 9.5.2.

Можно реализовать это на уровне приложения, но требуют, именно, на уровне СУБД. Чтобы она не дала нарушить это правило.

Comment: почитайте про триггера

Comment: Что-то вроде такого: `ADD CHECK type IS NULL OR type != 1 OR arg IS NULL` См документацию про CHECK, придумывайте как записать условие в одну строку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE test 
ADD CONSTRAINT null_arg 
CHECK ((type = 1 AND arg IS NULL) OR type <> 1)
```